# Themes for windows 7 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, software-rec, 32-bit, themes

I want to make my own themes, like the ones found on creativex.net. Is there a program out there that can help me with this ?

Comment: The url is as followed:
http://creativx.net/

Comment: If somebody has answered your question, it would be polite to accept their answer. If nobody has answered satisfactorily, you can post more information or edit your post and perhaps someone can better answer it.

Answer (score 1):

The website you refer to doesn't seem to work. I'm not entirely sure what kind of theme you're referring to, but if you just mean a packaged windows theme with specific window colors, sounds, screensavers and desktop backgrounds, you can do that easily from within windows. Just go to the desktop preferences dialog, set whatever theme preferences you want, then click "save theme". It will generate a theme file for you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean themes that dramatically alter the appearance of Windows 7's Aero interface, a lá WindowBlinds, you'll need two things:

1. A patched `UXTheme.dll`, which allows for custom, unsigned themes to be installed. Fiddling with this may or may not be in violation of Windows' EULA, so you're on your own for digging that up. (There's gotta be a reason why, of all things, Aero themes mandate cryptographic signing.)
2. A resource editor, such as [ResourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), to alter the individual bitmap images that make up a theme's resource file.

Be warned, last I looked the process looked pretty time-intensive. The default Aero theme has at least a thousand little bitmaps in it, and documentation on which need altering (if not all of them!) is/was scarce. You can find the default Aero theme in `%SystemRoot%\resources\Themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles`

Answer (score 0):

As nhinkle said, you can make them yourself directly from Windows 7. If you don't know how to do it, check this tutorial: [How to Customize Windows 7 Themes](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-customize-windows-7-themes)